# TrainImageContentDetector gives very poor result on GPU compared to CPU

Tags: image-processing, machine-learning

On the doc page of [TrainImageContentDetector](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TrainImageContentDetector.html), there is an example of heart detector training. I tried this example with different `TargetDevice` and constrained the `TimeGoal` to be 1 minute.

`dfCPU` is trained on CPU.

[image]

`dfGPU` is trained on GPU.

[image]

Now I pick an image like this

[image]

Now we test it as below

[image]

You can see CPU version is much better at detecting heart than GPU version. Why is that? Considering that GPU is much faster and get much more training within a minute, this result is strange. What is wrong with my training?

Comment: Can you give it 30mins?

Comment: @M.R. I tried 3 mins training on GPU, it improves a little by detecting 7 hearts. Of course, I can train it for 30mins. But that doesn't make any sense. I can see from progress plane that GPU process examples at a rate about 5 times faster than CPU. I would expect even 20 seconds of training on GPU will be better than CPU.

Comment: Seems like a bug, also needs to be able to export this to onnx pytorch and coreml

Comment: @user5601 Hi, What do you mean by "also needs to be able to export this to onnx pytorch and coreml"

Comment: This feature would be much more useful if the trained detector wasn't locked into wolfram, exportability and interoperability is super important!

Comment: @user5601 You can export to ONNX with `Export["mynet.onxx", net]`. I tried it successfully on simple networks only.

Comment: @anderstood 100 bucks that your net wasn't a detector, e.g. what this question is about ;)